# Close Fieldset when another is opened

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form at http://turtle.umbrellamedia.net/build

What I would like is to be able to open each field set group, and close the others. For instance, if I click on "Front Color" the "Type of Phone" field set would close.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I am using the forms API for this and have a custom module built that made these form items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for a jquery.ui accordion fieldgroup setup instead.

e.g: If you install https://drupal.org/project/field_group

I believe you can also use those group styles in custom FAPI forms. At least, I've done that for vertical tab, but maybe that's core now...

You could also add the javascript manually with

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
```

and use it as per: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Ended up getting rid of the field sets and going with "container" and using jquery ui. Thanks